# How Can I Uninstall Shairport?

Tags: shairplay

I have installed shairport on my raspberry pi by following various instructions but mainly from this:

http://snippets.khromov.se/raspberry-pi-shairport-build-instructions/

I would now like to know how to uninstall it but reversing the process does not seem to work.  I also set it up to run automatically.

How do I completely remove shairport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using dpkg to uninstall this package?

```
sudo dpkg -r shairport
```

If the boot script isn't automatically removed:

```
sudo chkconfig shairport off
```

or

```
sudo update-rc.d -f shairport remove
```

Also don't forget to remove this line in crontab (`crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * root /bin/sh /root/shairport-watchdog.sh > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

when you followed the instructions of this blog you can undo your steps like this:

1. remove shairport from boot scripts:

   `sudo update-rc.d -f shairport remove`
2. remove the init file

   `sudo rm /etc/init.d/shairport`
3. find the shairport program

   `sudo find /usr -name 'shairport'`

   the result will be in /usr/local/bin or /usr/sbin
4. delete the program

   `sudo rm /path/to/file/shairport`
5. search for soruces of shairport

   `sudo find / -name 'shairport'`
6. delete sources

   `sudo rm -r /path/to/sources`

maybe it is not recommented to purge the prereqirements you found in the blog post, becasue they might be used by other

i found the informations in this Blog post:

http://komputermaschine.blogspot.de/2015/01/shairport-vom-system-entfernen.html